# AngularJS model update reverting back to original

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, model-binding, angularjs-ng-click

http://plnkr.co/edit/3UMwSK6H5VL0pZujL7Qh?p=preview

Click edit and then cancel. The text boxes do not go away. Click cancel again, they go away. Please tell me why this is happening. I am losing my mind over this.

Thanks is advance. :)

Here is the code:

```js
function SmartTableController($scope) {

    $scope.sortFunc = function (keyname) {
        $scope.sortType = keyname;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    }

    $scope.editing = false;
    $scope.newField = {};

    
    $scope.editUsersTableFunc = function (user) {
        user.editing = true;
        $scope.newField = angular.copy(user);
        $scope.editing = $scope.usersTable.indexOf(user);       
    }

    $scope.saveField = function (user) {
        user.editing = false;
        $scope.newField = angular.copy(user);
        $scope.usersTable[$scope.editing] = $scope.newField;
    }

    $scope.resetFunc = function (user) {
        //$scope.newField = angular.copy(user);
        user.editing = false;
        $scope.usersTable[$scope.editing] = $scope.newField;
    }
    var OnEventChangeFunc = function () {
        $scope.lastItem = $scope.currentPage * $scope.itemsDisplayedPerPage;
        $scope.firstItem = $scope.lastItem - $scope.itemsDisplayedPerPage + 1;
        $scope.lastItem = $scope.lastItem > $scope.totalRecords ? $scope.totalRecords : $scope.lastItem;
       
    }
    $scope.itemsDisplayedPerPage = '5';
    $scope.currentPage = 1;

    $scope.$watch('itemsDisplayedPerPage', OnEventChangeFunc);
    $scope.$watch('currentPage', OnEventChangeFunc);

    $scope.usersTable =[{ firstName: "a", lastName: "b", emailId: "abc@efg.com", country: "US" },
    { firstName: "a", lastName: "b", emailId: "abc@efg.com", country: "US" },
    { firstName: "a", lastName: "b", emailId: "abc@efg.com", country: "US" }];
       
    
    $scope.totalRecords = $scope.usersTable.length;

   

 
    }


SmartTableController.$inject = ['$scope'];
angular.module('smartTable', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
angular.module('smartTable').controller('SmartTableController', SmartTableController);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="smartTable">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-smart-table/2.1.8/smart-table.js"></script>
    
    <script src="dirPagination.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="SmartTableController">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <label>Search : </label>
        <input type="search" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text to search" />
    </div>
    <div st-table="usersTable">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Index</th>

                    <!--<th > First Name</th>-->
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortFunc('firstName')">
                            First Name
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <!--<th ng-click="sortType='lastName'"> Last Name</th>-->
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortFunc('lastName')">
                            Last Name
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <!--<th ng-click="sortType='emailId'"> Email Id</th>-->
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortFunc('emailId')">
                            Email Id
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <!--<th ng-click="sortType='country'"> Country</th>-->
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortFunc('country')">
                            Country
                        </a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr dir-paginate="user in usersTable | orderBy : sortType : reverse| filter : search | itemsPerPage : itemsDisplayedPerPage" current-page="currentPage">
                    <td>
                   {{$index + firstItem}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" ng-if="user.editing" ng-model="user.firstName"/>
                        <span ng-if="!user.editing">{{user.firstName}}</span></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" ng-if="user.editing" ng-model="user.lastName"/>
                        <span ng-if="!user.editing">{{user.lastName}}</span></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" ng-if="user.editing" ng-model="user.emailId"/>
                        <span ng-if="!user.editing">{{user.emailId}}</span></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" ng-if="user.editing" ng-model="user.country"/>
                        <span ng-if="!user.editing">{{user.country}}</span></
                    <td><input type="button" ng-if="!user.editing" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editUsersTableFunc(user)" value="Edit"/>
                        <input type="submit" ng-if="user.editing" ng-click="saveField(user)" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    <input type="submit" ng-if="user.editing" ng-click="resetFunc(user);" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-primary" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
       
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what's going on:

**1)** When you click on "Edit" button it triggers `$scope.editUsersTableFunc(user)`. Here when you pass `user` as a parameter, you actually pass element of your `$scope.usersTable`. This is because of `dir-paginate="user in usersTable"` in *index.html*. So in `editUsersTableFunc()` function `user` equals to `$scope.usersTable[$scope.editing]` or equals to `{firstName: "a", lastName: "b", emailId: "abc@efg.com", country: "US"}` in other words. At first line in this function you write `user.editing = true;` and thereby now `$scope.usersTable[$scope.editing] = {firstName: "a", lastName: "b", emailId: "abc@efg.com", country: "US", editing: true}`. Note here is new property **editing: true**. At the next step you save **THIS** `user` in `$scope.newField` (copy it).

Are you still following?=)

**2)** Now when you click on "Cancel" button, `$scope.resetFunc()` triggers. You also pass `user` here. Which now has property **editing: true** (`user.editing === true`). Then you write `user.editing = false`. Yes, now `inputs` have to disappear...**but!** right after that you reassign your `user` via next line: `$scope.usersTable[$scope.editing] = $scope.newField;`. Yep, and now again `user.editing` is equal to **true** (so it is shown), because `$scope.newField` contain `user` with property **editing: true**.

**3)** When you click on "Cancel" second time, you pass **new** `user` as the parameter. You actually pass `$scope.usersTable[$scope.editing]` and in the end of **step 2)** it became `$scope.newField`. So now when you write `user.editing = false` you do `$scope.newField.editing = false`. And it works.

Hope you get it *=)*

Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LPh0PHYnWtNjXYym4T1A?p=preview) example on how you can fix it. I only changed `resetFunc`:

```
$scope.resetFunc = function (user) {
    $scope.newField.editing = false;
    $scope.usersTable[$scope.editing] = $scope.newField;
}
```